# Bluemix Container - Cannot access Private IP Between container

Tags: networking, containers, ibm-cloud

I have some problem with container in bluemix.
Private IP can't be accessed between containers
Some container still have "networking status" and the Public IP can't be accessed.

Answer (score 3):

'Networking' state means that the networking layer is being created for your Container so that the public and private IPs can be accessed. When a container gets stuck on Networking then it is typically a problem with the infrastructure and since the above process is not completed you are not able to access the container, both using the private and public IPs.

Please try to remove your container and recreate it (using the UI or the *cf ic run* command) to see if this resolves the problem. If not then I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the
  upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support
  widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of
  assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

In this way you will involve the IBM Containers team to check what's wrong with your running container.